# Polymer 1.0: How to set width of <paper-dropdown-menu>?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

[Here is the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xamejogobe/1/edit?html,output).

How would I style the `dropdown-menu` to be `800px` wide?

http://jsbin.com/xamejogobe/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>
<body>
<x-element></x-element>
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-menu {
        --paper-dropdown-menu: {
          width: 800px;
        };
      }
    </style>
    Click the below menu icon to make the dropdown menu appear.
    <br>
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-menu-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove `--paper-dropdown-menu`, you'll get the `800px` wide menu:

http://jsbin.com/cehanu/3/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

*Below updates imports of accepted answer.*

http://jsbin.com/xironutuqi/1/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Polymer Bin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
<x-element></x-element>
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-menu {
        width: 800px;
      }
    </style>
    Click the below menu icon to make the dropdown menu appear.
    <br>
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-menu-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-element'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```